# Camera Pose Estimation from Vanishing Points

Tags: computer-vision, camera, camera-calibration, camera-pose

I want to estimate the pose of camera (Location and Orientation). Can I use Vanishing Points to get the location and orientation of the camera?

There is object in the image which I also know his size, can it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the vanishing points to calibrate the camera. 
I recommend reading  Chapter 8.6 of *Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision* [ http://www.cambridge.org/9780521540513 ]

Even better, if you have those points on a known sized plane, then you can compute an homography *H* and the it is possible to compute both intrinsic and extrinsic camera matrices *[K],[R|T]* respectively.

The size of the object helps determining the scene scale, or more precisely the scale of the column vector *t* in the extrinsic matrix.
(Zhang's calibration method)[ https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/tr98-71.pdf ]